# How to <%# Eval() %> and alter a date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a link with parameters only if certain things are retrieved from the database.

Here is my code:

```
protected void GetOrderLines (string OrderID)
{
    string query;
    query = "SELECT ol.ItemId, ol.Amount, ol.Quantity, i.description, ol.RetailPrice, o.OrderDate";
    query += " FROM Distributor d";
    query += " INNER JOIN Orders o";
    query += " ON o.DistID = d.DistID";
    query += " INNER JOIN Orderlines ol";
    query += " ON ol.OrderID = o.OrderID";
    query += " INNER JOIN Items i";
    query += " ON i.InventoryID = ol.ItemID";
    query += " WHERE ol.OrderID = " + OrderID;
    query += " AND ol.GroupItem = 0";
    query += " AND d.DistID = " + Session[ "Distid" ];

    DataTable data = GeneralFunctions.GetData( query );

    RepeaterOrderlineInfo.DataSource = data;
    RepeaterOrderlineInfo.DataBind();
}
```

Here is the data it gives me:

```
ItemId  Amount  Quantity    description RetailPrice OrderDate
6015    660 1   Item 1  660 5/1/2012
6021    199.2   332 Item 2  0.6 5/1/2012
6018    150 6   Item 3  25  5/1/2012
9000    85  4   Technical Support   21.25   5/1/2012
8000    125 4   Custom Programming and Misc. Fees   31.25   5/1/2012
```

Here is the Eval code on the page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOrderlineInfo" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Itemid") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("description") %>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <%# Eval("RetailPrice", "{0:C}") %>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <%# Eval("Quantity") %>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <%# Eval( "Amount", "{0:C}" )%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am trying to build a link for the `<%# Eval("Description") %>`

```
<a href="SupportSummary.aspx?sd="<%# Eval("OrderDate") %>&ed=<%# Eval("OrderDate") //- 1 month %>"><%# Eval("Description") %>
```

I only need the description to be a link if the `description = "Technical Support"`.  Is this possible when using a repeater?

So the main things I am seeking here are:

How to Eval the OrderDaye and subtract one month.
How to do a condition on the description only if it = "Technical Support".

Comment: Little Bobby Tables is going to get you.

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. :)

Comment: He's trying to say that you're really opening yourself up to a sql injection attack by concatonating a string (presumably one that comes direct from a web form?) into your SQL query. Also I'd be super worried about where the Session["Distid"] is coming from. ADO.NET has really niced parameterized SqlCommands... use them! (and this is the reference http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Session["Distid"] comes straight from the database from when they log in.  OrderID could be injected I suppose.  I do use parameters in a lot of other places, but was unsure how to use them for what I was trying to do here.  I used someone elses existing GetData method.

Comment: If you can make `OrderId` an `int` in your method, that would help. If it has to be a string, perhaps you can add a regex to check that it is the format you are expecting. And cast Session["Distid"] to an int, too.

Comment: @mafue I converted the orderid to an int, will work on session["distid'] as well.  Thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a method to your code-behind, you can call it like this in your repeater:

```
<%# MyMethod(Eval("Description"),Eval("OrderDate")) %>
```

The method would be something like this:

```
protected string MyMethod(object description, object orderDate)
{ 
    string link = String.Empty;

    // conditions, assign link if needed

    return link;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to play with this, I think I understand this enough to integrate it in.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to switch to `OnItemCreated` with your repeater to get a lot of control over your outputted markup. It's pretty easy to do, like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOrderlineInfo" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="labelDate" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

RepeaterOrderlineInfo.ItemCreated += Repeater_ItemCreated;

protected void Repeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeatrItemCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as DataRow;

    if(dataItem != null)
    {
        Label labelDate = e.Item.FindControl("labelDate") as Label;

        if(labelDate != null && row["Description"] != "TechnicalSupport")
           labelDate.Text = // whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

This gives you extreme flexibility on making your table. Honestly, I would try to avoid `Eval(<string>)` as much as possible in your markup and instead deal with most of this in your code behind.

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked, but I could just not grasp how to integrate this into my existing stuff.  I'm still pretty new to asp.net.

Comment: This is the better method to use.  You can also Encrypt your OrderID in this method so that the concerns raised above about security are abolished.

Answer (score 1):

Tejs' and mafue's answers are right on but you can also do this >>

```
<%# Eval("Description").ToString().Equals("Technical Support", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? link : String.Empty %>
```